# Why does the Python script still run after truncating the file as it is being interpreted?

Tags: python, python-2.7

If i write  a python script (named as , say, test.py), in which I write code for opening test.py and truncating it, how does the interpreter still runs the script?

I read in the book "How to think like a computer scientist?" that

> An interpreter reads a high-level program and executes it, meaning that it does what the program says. It processes the program a little at a time, alternately reading lines and performing computations.

Then how does the interpreter run the script even after truncating it a few moments ago?

Here is the code :

```
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

print "We're going to erase %r." % filename
print "If you don't want that, hit CTRL-C (^C)."
print "If you do want that, hit RETURN."
raw_input("?")

print "Opening the file..."
target = open(filename, 'w')
print "Truncating the file Goodbye!"
target.truncate()

print "Now I'm going to ask you for three lines"

line1 = raw_input("line 1: ")
line2 = raw_input("line 2: ")
line3 = raw_input("line 3: ")

print "I'm going to write these to the file."
target.write(line1 + "\n" + line2 + "\n" + line2 + "\n")
```

Comment: See [Wikipedia: Interpreter (Computing)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_(computing)) - "an interpreter is a computer program that directly executes [source code], i.e. performs, instructions written in a programming or scripting language, without [*explicitly*] previously compiling them into a machine language program." It then goes on to list different common implementation scenarios. The language used in the book is misleading and not fully qualified.

Answer (score 3):

Very few modern interpreters work that way. In particular, Python actually compiles source Python into bytecode, then executes that bytecode without ever looking back on the Python source itself.

Comment: And if you've ever run batch (cmd.exe) programs with notepad open while making changes.. you'll probably be glad that there is such a separation of phases. I've rarely seen more confusing error messages code :}